# LF in data sent to socket

Tags: sockets, tcl

even that I have Tcl server socket configured with `fconfigure $s -translation binary` on the reception side I receive 0x0A (LF) as the last byte of message.
How to avoid it?

EDIT:
The code which translates hex string to binary data and sends it:

```
set tm_packet [binary format H* $tm_packet]
global sock
if {$sock != 0} {   
    if {[catch {puts $sock $tm_packet} result]} {
        syslog "ErrorMsg: $result"
        close $sock
        set sock 0
    }
    flush $sock
}
```

Where `tm_packet` is a sequence of hex values e.g.: `10b9a5`

On the client side `10b9a50a` is received in that case.

Comment: Generally speaking, you have to make sure both ends agree on the communications protocol.   If one end is treating the data as text and append a LF, you have a disagreement in protocol.

Comment: @BradLanam I agree. I just want to not append a LF on the source end.

Comment: The `flush` can also throw an exception, in fact it's  more likely to than the `puts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `puts` command will automatically append a newline to the output.

To prevent this with binary data, use the `-nonewline` option:

```
if {[catch {puts -nonewline $sock $tm_packet} result]} {
```

References: [puts](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm)